# Relative path to WCF service from MVC web config path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

So the story is that I need multiple test sites on a single IIS.

My application consists of a MVC project with a web.config file pointing towards the WCF Service located on the same server.

I have this folder structure on the IIS:

Developer1

-MVC

-WCF

Developer2

-MVC

-WCF

I have configured IIS so the devs can access

```
http://MyServer/Developer1/MVC
```

or

```
http://MyServer/Developer2/MVC
```

I have tried setting this path in the web.config file to contact the correct WCF `"~/WCF/SomeService.svc"` and `"../WCF/SomeService.svc"` but I can't get it to work and I can't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use a relative path? You could register both endpoints and use the one you need:

```
<endpoint name="dev1" address="http://MyServer/Developer1/MVC/WCF/SomeService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="SomeServiceContract" />

<endpoint name="dev2" address="http://MyServer/Developer1/MVC/WCF/SomeService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="SomeServiceContract" />

var svcProxy = new SomeServiceProxy("dev1");
```